# Display error message box with a "detail" button in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling

I've seen this kind of error box in Windows 7 (I can't remember exactly when): There is the error message, a OK button and a "detail" button. The "detail" button show debug information.
Is there a native class in C# I can use to show that kind of error box where I could show the stack trace when the person clicks on the "detail" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you saw was probably a [task dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), something new Microsoft added in Windows Vista to replace the old MessageBox APIs. Task dialogs support checkboxes, radio buttons, progress bars, "show more" expand/collapse, and a few other things as well.

The .NET Framework doesn't ship with an API for using task dialogs, but <s>the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/) adds support for them</s>. **Updated:** The Windows API Code Pack has been discontinued, but [Ookii.Dialogs](http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/) is a third-party library with support for task dialogs.